# Sequlize join two tables with same foreign key

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have one table Project with the foreign key product_id from Product table,

Project table:

```
project_id  | project_name | product_id
1           | project1     | 1
2           | project2     | 2
3           | project3     | 1
4           | project4     | 3
```

and another table Role has the same foreign key product_id too.
Role table:

```
role_id  | role_name | product_id
1        | role1     | 1
2        | role2     | 2
3        | role3     | 1
4        | role4     | 3
5        | role5     | 1
6        | role6     | 3
```

I'm trying to find all roles for a project with same product_id, for example with project1, what I expect to get are role1, role3 and role5 via its product_id, 1.

Is there a way on Sequlize to query in one statment? What I get currently is get the product_id of a project first, then find all roles with this product_id, which is two statments. I'm using Sql Server.

This is what I've tried:

```
const product = await Project.findOne({
    where: {
        projectId,
    },
    attributes: ["productId"],
})
const productId = product.productId
if (productId == null)
    return res.status(400).send({ status: 2, msg: "We were unable to find a product type on this project.", code: "EPRODUCTNF" })
const role = await Role.findAll({
    where: {
        productId,
    },
})
res.status(200).send(role)
```

The relationship I set is:

```
Product.belongsTo(Role, { targetKey: "productId", foreignKey: "productId", as: "roles" })
Product.belongsTo(Project, { targetKey: "productId", foreignKey: "productId", as: "projects" })
Project.hasMany(Product, { sourceKey: "productId", foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" })
Role.hasMany(Product, { sourceKey: "productId", foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const project = await Project.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Role,
      as: "products",
    },
  ],
});

// you access all role of Project using
let roles = project[0].Role;
```